Is there a safe way to detect extended keys on the Windows console?
I'm creating a library for easier console input and output (basically a kind of engine I could use for something like VIM). So I use _getch() for character-wise input under Windows.
However, I'm facing trouble when it comes to the so-called "extended keys" - just like under Linux with the 0x1B (ESC), Windows also defines multi-byte input values. For Linux, I use select to read all the consecutive characters in a row. But Windows' version of select is not fully implemented and is no option for that.
In Windows, those "extended keys" start with either 0x00 or 0xE0. While 0x00 is no problem, 0xE0 is - because for traditional code pages, 0xE0 is usually it's own character (Windows-1252 defines it as à), and even for UTF-8, 0xE0 can be a valid first byte of a character (e.g. everybody's favorite Unicode character, ඞ - it's encoded as 0xE0 0xB6 0x9E). And using the UTF-16 _getwch() doesn't help too, as 0x00E0=U+00E0 is also a valid Unicode value.
I already tried _kbhit() too, it also returns nonzero when I press multiple keys "at the same time", unlike select on Linux with a timeout of 0.
So my question is: is there any way to tell if the next character still belongs to the same input or not?
I basically want the following code example completed:
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    bool bExit = false;
    
    while (!bExit)
    {
        std::string sInput = (char)_getch();
        
        while (NextKeyBelongsToSameInput()) // <-- what function to use?
        {
            sInput += (char)_getch();
        }
        
        // (process sInput)
        
        bExit = sInput == "\x1B"; // exit on ESC
    }
    
    return 0;
}

I would really prefer to stick to Win32 functions and not use 3rd party libraries.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
